# Fragment communication. I am a bit confused

Tags: android, fragment

I have 2 fragments, FragA and FragB, and I want to pass a string from FragA to FragB.  I have used these references, http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity & http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

and I am still a bit confused on my next step.  What would I need to do to this code to get the string in FragA to FragB?  Please post code.

I have in my FragA:

```
public class FragA extends ListFragment{

    OnDataPass dataPasser;


public interface OnDataPass{
    public void onDataPass(String data);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(a.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

...
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String libraryList;

    //Get the position the user clicked.
    Fragment newFragment = null;

    libraryList = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    dataPasser.onDataPass(libraryList);
 ...
}
```

In my main activity I added:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDataPass{
...
    @Override
public void onDataPass(String data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

FragB:

```
public class FragB extends ListFragment{

TestAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(getActivity());     
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();

    //Get info from FragA

    //Close the database.
    mDbHelper.close();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement your `OnDataPass` interface in `FragB`, then in `Activity.onDataPass` you should find `FragB` instance and call `FragB.onDataPass`. Thats a clearest way I think.

Comment: So then in Activity.onDataPass (which is "public void onDataPass(String data)" right?) how would I find the FragB instance?

Comment: `((FragB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragB_tag"))`

Comment: You also need to set tag in layout file with `android:tag` attribute. Or set it manually if you adding fragment programmatically through transaction